# Examples of high/low central tendency and volatily

Tags: central-tendency

There are two important measures for any data set. Its central tendency and its variability. These provide measures of expectation and variability/volatility, respectively.

Can there be examples of:

1. Clear central tendency, no volatility.
2. Clear central tendency, with volatility.
3. Unclear central tendency, no volatility.
4. Unclear central tendency, with volatility.

Answer (score 0):

1. All values in dataset take a constant value: clear central tendency, there's no volatility
2. Clear central tendency, with volatility: any strong unimodal (single tall peak in histogram) distribution. For example, check normal distribution curves. There's volatility but central tendency is visible.
3. Unclear central tendency, no volatility: I can't think of any example. Lack of central tendency implies there's some variability in the data.
4. Unclear central tendency with volatility: think of uniform distribution or throw of a (unloaded) dice in discrete case. All values are equally likely so no clear central tendency exists.